# Proof that if g is continuous at a and $g(a) ≠ 0$, then there exists $δ > 0$ such that $g(x) ≠ 0$ for all $x ∈ (a−δ,a + δ).$

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence, continuity

Deﬁnition of continuous:. We say that a function $f$ is continuous at a provided that for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that if $|x−a| < \delta$ then $|f(x)−f(a)| < \epsilon$.

Prove that if $g$ is continuous at $a$ and $g(a) ≠ 0$, then there exists $δ > 0$ such that $g(x) ≠ 0$ for all $x ∈ (a−δ,a + δ)$.

[Hint: Consider the case where $g(a) > 0$. Use the deﬁnition with $\epsilon = \frac {g(a)}2$ , For the case $g(a) < 0$, consider the function $−g$.]

**Could you please check my answer ?**

MY answer

Case 1:

assume $g(a)>o$ , let $\epsilon = g(a)/2$

let $\epsilon>o$ ,there exists $δ > 0 , |x−a| < δ$, so  $|g(x)-g(a)|<\frac {g(a)}2$

So, $\frac {g(a)}2<g(x)-g(a)<\frac{g(a)}2$  $→$ $g(a)-(\frac {g(a)}2)<g(x)<(\frac{g(a)}2) +g(a)$

→$g(x)>g(a)-\frac{g(a)}2$

→$g(x)> \frac{g(a)}2 >0$

So, $g(x)>o$  for all $x ∈ (a−δ,a + δ)$.

Case 2:

Assume $g(a)<0$ , consider  $–g(a) >0$ so that there exists $ δ$ such that $–g(a) >0$ , for all $ x ∈ (a−δ,a + δ)$.

So, $g(x)<0$ for all $x∈ (a−δ,a + δ)$.

Comment: Just let $\epsilon = |g (a)|/2$ rather than two cases.  Otherwise looks great.

Comment: @fleablood thanks, I see it now.

Comment: Or not... I see your cases weren't redundant after all.